# c - Why do I get this SIGSEGV? How do I know how much memory a struct can get?

Tags: c

I pasted my code here: http://pastebin.com/tPvRHrkW
Compiled with `gcc`. 
It seems the error occurred because I defined a struct too big for the compiler. I took the struct out into another single source file and tested it, no error occurred this time. So why am I getting SIGSEGV and is there any limit on the size of a struct?

Comment: Where did it seg fault? Have you run it through a debugger at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a limit to the size of the struct, the problem is with how you're using it. `MGraph` is the huge structure type, and in two places you're using it in a manner that places it on the stack; once as a parameter to a function and again as a local variable. Stack space is often not something that is permitted to grow to huge proportions.

I would suggest two changes. First, use dynamic allocation for instances of this type. Second, pass pointers as parameters to it, rather than the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you're only limited by available memory and the addressing capabilities of your system. However in your case you're declaring a local variable, which will be allocated on the stack. The stack is likely much more limited in capacity.

Comment: I tried a even larger array and it still works. Seems no limit here.

Answer (score 1):

`#define MAXV 20000` .. `int edges[MAXV][MAXV];`

is 20000 * 20000 * 4 ~ 1.5 Gigs of memory on stack.

You should probably use [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) & dynamically allocate instead.

Comment: I never expected it takes so much memory~ Thanks~